# Eclipse Maven Setup

Tags: eclipse, maven

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxOfo.jpg)while creating maven project it is not creating maven project it is strucked at downloading maven dependency. Can anyone help me to solve this issue

I tried to create maven project, Its totally strucked unable to create maven project

Comment: It's asking for your confirmation at the bottom.

Comment: It wants you to type Y in the console to confirm.